# How to dispatch from react-hook-form + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form (https://react-hook-form.com/).
I would like to dispatch action from inside of react-hook-form.

In following case, I am supposed to dispatch using `props.dispatch`, when onSubmit is fired.

However I could not figure out how to dispatch and update state by setState.

```
import React from 'react'
import useForm from 'react-hook-form'

export default function App(props) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = data => { 
           console.log(data);
           props.dispatch({type: 'CONFIRM'}); //--> Worked!!  
        }

  console.log(watch('example')) // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
      <input name="exampleRequired" ref={register({ required: true })} />      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Does anyone give me an advice?

```
class Sample extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mode: 'input'
        }
    }

    render() {
        switch (this.state.mode) {
            case 'input':
                return (<App />);
            case 'confirm':
                return (<App01 />);
            default:
                return (<App02 />);
        }
    }
}

export default connect((state)=>state)(Sample);
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with useForm. You need to connect() your App, then you have props.dispatch

Comment: I added `export default connect((state)=>state)(App);
` the end of code as if component class do. However I don't get props inside of App(). I think it is not component class, but function I thought.

Comment: You are not accepting props yet, should be: `export default function App(props)`

Comment: How can I give props from the parent component `<App />`?

Answer (score 5):

Using dispatch with redux has nothing to do with `react-hook-form` library.

If you using [`redux-hooks`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks), which is [an alternative for `connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#hooks) and a better approach if you using hooks anyway with `react-hook-form`:

> React's new "hooks" APIs give function components the ability to use local component state, execute side effects, and more.
>
> React Redux now offers a set of hook APIs as an alternative to the existing connect() Higher Order Component. These APIs allow you to subscribe to the Redux store and dispatch actions, without having to wrap your components in connect().

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // use distpach
}
```

If you using [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/connect):

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
function App({ dispatch }) {
  // use dispatch
}

export default connect()(App);
```

Comment: If I would like to use both of `props.dispatch` and `props.setState`, do you have better way?

Comment: What does `props.setState` means? Where does it come from?

Comment: I would like to change state in this module. My understanding is `props` are parameter which have setState and dispatch method.  --> https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

Comment: Ok so where is the problem? If you connected the `App` to redux store you can use `props.dispatch`

Comment: You don't have `App(props)` in your example, please read the answer carefully.

Comment: I change like `function App({ props }) {` , however it does not work.

Comment: `function App({props}) {
    const onSubmit = data => {
        props.dispatch({type: 'CONFIRM'});
    }; `

Comment: Again, `function App(props)` and use `props.dispatch` or `function App({ dispatch })`, its basic javascript.

Comment: I could have `props.dispatch()` work. However I don't still figure out how to change state??? I need to update state.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out.
I am using `combineReducers`. It is distracted.
I should have written like following.

```
combineReducers({
    sample01: sample01Reducer, sample02: sample02Reducer,    //Reducers
```

```
class Sample extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mode: 'input'
        }
    }

    render() {
        switch (this.props.sample01.mode) {
            case 'input':
                return (<App />);
            case 'confirm':
                return (<App01 />);
            default:
                return (<App02 />);
        }
    }
}

export default connect((state)=>state)(Sample);
```